# Android Start task within specific time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want my task to be started at 12, 3, 6, 9 pm on every day. To these hours, a method should be called. How can I implement such a scenario. If anyone can grant a resource or code example, it is admirable.

Comment: http://tasker.dinglisch.net/ - If you don't want to make your own app.

Comment: I found a way.
//Create alarm manager
AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//Create pending intent & register it to ur alarm notifier class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the AlarmManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Search stack for examples, here is one [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)