# Automatically change to new date for display date in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have set display current date on textview in my android app, it work, but it doesn't change to new date auto after 00:00:00 AM until we close App and open back.Please help. Here is my code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    String ct = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
    tv.setText(ct);
```

Comment: This is happening because that initialization happens only ones

Comment: so please advice what i can do to let it initialization always

Comment: you want to change `TextView` content only at 12:00 ?

Comment: You would need to decide when you want the date to change (e.g. onResume would happen when returning from an activity started from this activity, or you could have a button an change on the onClick (when button is clicked)).

Comment: you can also user `AlarmManager` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700003/android-start-task-within-specific-time

Comment: no i don't want to use button, i want it automatically change by itself at 12:00 AM

Answer (score 4):

It's gonna be a pretty good amount of code to add, but, here's what you have to do.

Assuming that you have a class extending `Activity`, you'll need to override `onPause()` and `onResume()`.
For example:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

In these two methods, you are going to have to register and unregister an `IntentFilter`.
Create the `IntentFilter` as a global variable. We'll also create the listener that'll be used later.

```
private IntentFilter filter;
private final BroadcastReceiver listener;
```

Instantiate it in your `onCreate()`.

```
filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
```

Also, directly after that, we'll create the listener to tell it what to do when the date changes.

```
listener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        String ct = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
        tv.setText(ct);
    }
};
```

Finally, we have to register and unregister the listener when the app opens and closes.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(listener, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(listener);
}
```

And, there you have it! Should automatically update when the date changes now. Also, I wouldn't recommend re-initializing the `TextView` every time the date changes, but your current code was that, so I left it.

More info from [Ben English](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230951/2197529)

Comment: I am not so understand

Comment: Which parts? Maybe I can help. @SamithFP

Comment: Does your Java file extend Activity? @SamithFP

Comment: I have follow your code, but the problem is on super.onResume, and on super.onPause is red, so what is error